# OOP C++ - Error as A.h includes B.h which includes A.h again

Tags: c++, oop, header, include

I'm learning OOP and have a doubt. Suppose I have a file **ClassA.h** that includes **ClassB.h**, and at some point my **ClassB.h** needs to include **ClassA.h**.

This yelds an error and I think I understand why that happens since I get an infinite include loop. But what to do in this case? Is there a way around this error? Or should I rethink my classes to avoid it? Does this mean my class organization is poorly designed? If so, what would be a way to arrange my "class diagram" and avoid this?

I just want to know what would be the best practice in this scenario. Also, why doesn't the "#pragma once" directive solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was supposed to have a hyphen to separate the title, I'll add that now, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Generally it is customary to include a code snippet of actual code that causes the problem. It can be a test case that you make up just to post here as long as it actually has the problem you're asking about and you've tested it to make sure. The reason why is that it's very hard to give a good specific answer to a question like this.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to fix it, but it also means your class organization is broken.

The way to fix it is called an 'include guard', though many compilers also support the `#pragma once` directive. I suppose it isn't working because `#pragma once` probably doesn't consider a header file included until the entire thing is parsed. And since the recursive inclusion happens in the middle of the header file, it isn't finished being parsed yet.

An include guard is something like this:

In ClassA.h:

```
#pragma once // Just because. It really should help.
#ifndef INCLUDED_CLASSA_H
#define INCLUDED_CLASSA_H

#include "ClassB.h"

//... rest of header file

#endif
```

In ClassB.h:

```
#pragma once // Just because. It really should help.
#ifndef INCLUDED_CLASSB_H
#define INCLUDED_CLASSB_H

#include "ClassA.h"

//... rest of header file

#endif
```

The organization problem is called a circular dependency, and circular dependencies are generally a bad idea. There are a number of different ways of breaking them, but which to use depends on the exact nature of and original reason for the dependency.

Depending on the problem you can use one of a variety of techniques:

- Inheritance from a common base class
- Turning one of the two classes into a base class for the other *- This is a variant of the previous one.*
- Forward declarations - This is not so desired because it doesn't really break the circular dependency, it just arranges it so you don't need to also have a problematic circular include dependency.
- Turning some part of both classes into a class that they both can use *- This is another variant of common base class that uses composition instead of inheritance.*

There are other techniques. There is, in fact, a book that has a really wide variety of techniques to use in various situations because removing circular dependencies is a big theme of the book. That book is ["Large-Scale C++ Software Design" by John Lakos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620).

Comment: So #ifndef guards work differently from #pragma once? Anyway, I just tested it and got the same problem. I'll try to rearrange things to get around this if it's bad practice.

Comment: @LeandroNogueiraCouto: Those should've worked. What, exactly, is the error you're getting? And yes, it's bad practice. :-) They work differently because `#pragma once` is implemented by the compiler in the preprocessor in whatever way the vendor sees fit (since it's just a widely supported extension). Whereas those `#ifdef` guards rely on well specified features.

Comment: I get a ton of errors, over 100, bizarre syntax errors and "undeclared identifiers". 

Knowing the name of the problem helps a lot, I googled Circular Dependencies and found a simple forward declaration helps in my particular case, among other solutions involving refactoring my clases.

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for the detailed answer and for mentioning possible work-arounds! Very helpful.

Comment: @LeandroNogueiraCouto: If you have to use forward declarations to deal with a circular dependency issue with a class in another header file, that's a sign that maybe you should rethink that. Typically their best used to handle a circular dependency within a single header file. Which is often not the best state of affairs, but is sometimes a good idea. Circular dependencies between header files are almost never a good idea. And circular dependencies between modules should be considered forbidden. And, you're welcome. That's what we're here for. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You may also get around this by using forward declaration. Provided you do not create actual object of the class you are including in the header or not inheriting from it, say if you only need pointers of them in the headers you can do this.

Example:

```
ClassA.h
class ClassB;
//rest of the codes here

ClassB.h
class ClassA;
//rest of the codes here

ClassA.cpp
#include ClassA.h
#include ClassB.h

ClassB.cpp
#include ClassB.h
#inlcude ClassA.h
```

Answer (score -1):

In my past experience , I have solved same problem by using Inheritance.

The way I have solved is .
ClassA -> ClassB : ClassB was inherited by ClassA. 
ClassA had common needs that ClassB and ClassA wanted.

then I had resolved "Recursive Include Problem"

Comment: #include problems unrelated to inheritance -- for example, you could have the exact same problem with #includes in C, which doesn't support inheritance.